# Nesting setInterval function to successfully change canvas's context for multiple canvas animations

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, setinterval

Here is what I am attempting to do. As of the moment I have 2 canvas elements, however, I am expecting to expand upon them (e.g., add more). In either case, I currently have everything working fine in one canvas element, however, I want to switch from one canvas element to another (via the pre-built changeContext() function in the code below), in an iterative fashion. I am attempting to have one animation fire off through the beginAnimation() function, then *after* that is complete, the canvas context is changed to the next canvas while the next instantiated object is pushed through the beginAnimation() function. I have a feeling that I might have to do this by nesting either setInterval and/or setTimeout functions, however, I am not too adept at either one.

Any feedback, comments, and/or suggestions would surely be appreciated.

```
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded() { canvasApp(); }

function canvasSupport() { return Modernizr.canvas; }

function canvasApp() {

// if: no canvas support return, else declare 2D canvas
if (!canvasSupport()) { return; } else {
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById('cvs-1');
    var context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
}

function changeContext(num) {
    theCanvas = document.getElementById('cvs-' + num);
    context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
}

var stepStart = 0;
var stepEnd = 0.00;

// Constructor: myPercentage
var myPercentage = function(percentage) {
    this.strokeStyle = '#2B5981';                       // Blue
    this.lineWidth = 10;
    this.percentage = percentage;                       // Percentage
    this.degrees = this.percentage * 360.0;
    this.radians = this.degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    this.x = 57.5;
    this.y = 57.5;
    this.r = 45;
    this.s = 1.5 * Math.PI;
    this.drawShape = function() {
        context.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        function clearCanvas(x,y,width,height) {
            context.rect(x,y,width,height);
            context.fillStyle = '#FCFCFC';
            context.fill();
        }
        function circle(x,y,r,startAngle,endAngle,counterClockwise) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x,y,r,startAngle,endAngle,counterClockwise);
            context.shadowColor = '#242424';
            context.shadowBlur = 7;
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
        }
        function writePercentage(percentage) {
            context.font = '20px Georgia';
            context.fillStyle = 'black';
            context.fillText(Math.round(percentage*100)+'%',40,62);
        }
        clearCanvas(0,0,115,115);
        this.degrees = this.percentage * 360.0;
        this.radians = this.degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        circle(this.x,this.y,this.r,this.s,this.radians+this.s,false);
        writePercentage(this.percentage);
        context.save();
    };
};

function setSteps(object) {
    stepStart = 0;
    stepEnd = object.percentage * 100;
    object.percentage = 0.00;
}

//Instantiate: new percentages
var phpPerc = new myPercentage(0.75);
var jsPerc = new myPercentage(0.25);

function beginAnimation(object) {

    setSteps(object);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (stepStart < stepEnd) {
            object.percentage += 0.01;
            object.drawShape();
            stepStart++;
        } else {
            clearInterval();
        }
    }, 33);
}

beginAnimation(phpPerc);
// changeContext(2);
// beginAnimation(jsPerc);
```

A demo of this should be accessible here -> http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/TS8w7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that absolutely gave me the insight that I required to complete this little project, I sincerely do appreciate it. However, I am a little confused and conflicted with the whole concept upon how utilizing various (or multiple) canvases would generate unwanted overhead. I do understand, and absolutely appreciate you prompting me concerning the process of continuously utilizing the getElementById() function throughout runtime, which would (more than likely) generate unnecessary overhead during animation. However, I have read throughout various articles that the  element is already optimized as a DOM element so that it does not require post-production optimization when using either multiple canvases, or multiple canvas layers.

**References:**

Ranfelt, A., (2013). Optimize HTML5 canvas rendering with layering. IBM developerWorks.
     Retrieved from: http://tinyurl.com/m3yx682

N.A., (2013). Is using multiple canvas objects a good practice? *Game Development Stack 
     Exchange*. Retrieved from: http://tinyurl.com/l4dlv6a

N.A., (2010). HTML5 multiple canvas on a single page. *Stack Overflow Stack Exchange*.
     Retrieved from: http://tinyurl.com/ll3o7vv

Litten, J. (2010). Using Multiple HTML5 Canvases as Layers. Unknown Kadath.
     Retrieved from: http://tinyurl.com/6yspxzu

Albeit, this original post inquired upon how to **Nest setInterval functions to successfully change canvas's context for multiple canvas animations**, I was able to subvert this by essentially changing stepStart & stepEnd single variables to arrays. In addition, I naturally also changed my original constructor method (shown below) to reflect the various canvas elements stored (now) throughout arrays, while including additional arguments to be passed through the main constructor, including the beginAnimation() method; negating the need to even have a changeContext() method, let alone nested setInterval functions. Albeit, this method definitely works, I hope that the solution does not deviate too much from the original inquiry. Regardless, I sincerely do appreciate your feedback **markE**, and thank you for your time. The updated code below should work as intended, and there is also an updated version of it here (http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/TS8w7/1/), in case anyone wants to utilize it for their own projects.

```
// Declare: canvases array to store multiple canvas elements
var canvases=[];
    canvases.push(document.getElementById('cvs-1'));
    canvases.push(document.getElementById('cvs-2'));

// Declare: contexts array to store '2d' canvas API
var contexts=[];

// Store: '2d' canvas API throughout canvases array
for(var i=0; i<canvases.length; i++ ) {
    contexts.push(canvases[i].getContext('2d'));

}

// stepStart & stepEnd arrays
var stepStart=[];
var stepEnd=[];

// Constructor: myPercentage(percentage, context)
var myPercentage = function(percentage,ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;                                 // Context
    this.strokeStyle = '#2B5981';                       // Blue
    this.lineWidth = 10;
    this.percentage = percentage;                       // Percentage
    this.degrees = this.percentage * 360.0;
    this.radians = this.degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    this.x = 57.5;
    this.y = 57.5;
    this.r = 45;
    this.s = 1.5 * Math.PI;
    this.drawShape = function() {
        contexts[ctx].strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        contexts[ctx].lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        function clearCanvas(x,y,width,height) {
            contexts[ctx].rect(x,y,width,height);
            contexts[ctx].fillStyle = '#FCFCFC';
            contexts[ctx].fill();
        }
        function circle(x,y,r,startAngle,endAngle,counterClockwise) {
            contexts[ctx].beginPath();
            contexts[ctx].arc(x,y,r,startAngle,endAngle,counterClockwise);
            contexts[ctx].shadowColor = '#242424';
            contexts[ctx].shadowBlur = 7;
            contexts[ctx].stroke();
            contexts[ctx].closePath();
        }
        function writePercentage(percentage) {
            contexts[ctx].font = '20px Georgia';
            contexts[ctx].fillStyle = 'black';
            contexts[ctx].fillText(Math.round(percentage*100)+'%',40,62);
        }
        clearCanvas(0,0,115,115);
        this.degrees = this.percentage * 360.0;
        this.radians = this.degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        circle(this.x,this.y,this.r,this.s,this.radians+this.s,false);
        writePercentage(this.percentage);
        contexts[ctx].save();
    };
};

// Identify: number of steps to take between object's percentage
function setSteps(object) {
    stepStart[object.context] = 0;
    stepEnd[object.context] = object.percentage * 100;
    object.percentage = 0.00;
}

//Instantiate: new percentages
var onePerc = new myPercentage(0.90,0);
var twoPerc = new myPercentage(0.80,1);

// Initialize: animation with passed object
function beginAnimation(object) {

    setSteps(object);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (stepStart[object.context] < stepEnd[object.context]) {
            object.percentage += 0.01;
            object.drawShape();                         // Uncaught Reference
            stepStart[object.context]++;
        }
    }, 33);
}

// Call: animations to be executed
beginAnimation(onePerc,0);
beginAnimation(twoPerc,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Making DOM requests like .getElementById are relatively expensive.

Better is to get reference to all your canvases and contexts at the start of your app.

```
// get all canvas and context references once at the start of your app

var canvases=[];
canvases.push(document.getElementById('cvs-1'));
canvases.push(document.getElementById('cvs-2'));
canvases.push(document.getElementById('cvs-3'));

var contexts=[];
for(var i=0;i<canvases.length;i++){
    contexts.push(canvases[i].getContext('2d');
}
```

Then you can set your `theCanvas` and `context` variables to any desired canvas & context.

```
function changeContext(num) {
    theCanvas = canvases[num];
    context = contexts[num];
}
```

BTW, You might want to test your code using a single canvas instead of multiple canvases.  Canvas is built to handle multiple sets of drawings quickly and efficiently.  You might find 1 canvas is fast enough and takes less resources than multiple canvases.